# bower init - what is the purpose of the 'private' option in bower.json?

Tags: json, bower

I am creating a `bower.json` file from scratch for the first time. I ran:

```
bower init
```

then I followed the step by step instructions. I was asked the following:

> would you like to mark this package as private which prevents it from being accidentally published to the registry? (y/N)

I chose `y`(**Yes**), but I don't really understand what it means.

In my `bower.json` file I have the following line:

```
"private": true,
```

What is the purpose of this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying you are located in a folder which is the root folder of the bower package you are currently developing to package your new custom library.

The command `bower register <package-name> <git-repo-url>` will register the current bower package to the declared bower registry (by default, bower.herokuapp.com, but you can override it by your private bower package registry).

> ... unless your `bower.json` file contain the `private:true` option. If so, bower will cancel registring your package to your configured registry.

Answer (score 6):

If you create a package and if you want that package not to be listed in bower search then you have to pass the flag private to be true.

http://bower.io/search/